# How to understand the gradient flow in Densenet showed in the article of CSP-Net?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ginW9.png)

Hellow,I wonder why the latter layers(which are close to the end of the whole network) in the DenseNet can use the gradient of former layers to update their weights just like the formulas showed in the artical of CSP-Net.I think the opposite is true,i.e.,the former layers can get all gradients of latter layers.Is there something wrong with my understanding of these formulas in CSP-Net.

Comment: Its probably a bit late. But stumbled upon the same question recently and as I understand it: each weight receives all gradients, computed previously as a vector, and then we apply it iteratively using cycle. like `for grad in grads: w = w - lr * grad`.

Comment: The same as standard forward pass, but for  weights, and instead of convolutions we have gradients